# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectmobilecloud/com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity}:

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo"

I was searching a lot of same case and tried to fix it, but it is really hard to fix this problem for beginner of android.

I am getting error like

> 11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectmobilecloud/com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
>   11-14 23:42:20.624: E/AndroidRuntime(1069):     ... 11 more

and  On the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      public MainSelection_Tool mt = new MainSelection_Tool();
      private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
      private RadioGroup radioWorkGroup;
      private RadioButton radioSexButton;
      private Button btnDisplay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
        public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        radioWorkGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioWorkFlow);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int workflow_id = radioWorkGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Intent GO_Control = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ControlActivity.class);
                int wf =    mt.Get_Option(workflow_id, 0);
                int si =    mt.Get_Option(selectedId, 1);
                System.out.println("Sel " + si + "  wf " + wf);
                Log.d("WORK", String.valueOf(wf));
                Log.d("Select", String.valueOf(si));

                startActivity(GO_Control);

            }

        });

      }
```

And
AndroidManifest.xml file I have...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.projectmobilecloud"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ControlActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

To be honest , I am not really sure how to fix it.

I just import project from the google code and I tried to run it.

From my teammate's laptop , it was working fine.

However, When I checked out and tried to run it. I didn't work..

Comment: Clean your project and run it once?

Comment: are you testing the app on emulator?

Comment: yep, i am testing with emulator...

Answer (score 0):

Try

> Project - Clean... -> select your project and clean it ..

Comment: I cleaned and ran it again but it still has problem... is there any possible reason ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.projectmobilecloud"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

jast add in your AndroidManifest xml. hope its work

Comment: i added and re-run it, but it still has problem , is this problem ? android:name="com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity"

Comment: <application
  android:name="com.example.projectmobilecloud"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.projectmobilecloud.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: <activity android:name=".ControlActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

Comment: Still doesn't work. What is the most reasons to make this error ? :(

Comment: I just import from google code. This project was originally in the my teammate's laptop

Comment: if you dont mieand send me your full project and i will fix it

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/projectmobilecloud/  this is project folder in google code.....

Comment: thanks for helping me :) Sorry, I really have no idea and this is the first time doing android project...

Comment: in the xml file i found "Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes 
 apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the 
 android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details."

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated to **ADTv17** or above, the old **ProGuard** files will do this to you. Create a new empty project, and see project.properties and proguard-properties and modify your current project accordingly.

Comment: In the AndroidManifest xml, I found Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes 
 apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the 
 android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details. is it cause of error ?

Comment: no, it could be because your project.properties and progard-properties are not created properly. Try to edit that in referance to a project created in eclipse